# Can't use Twilio TaskRouter.js in my react app

Tags: node.js, twilio-api

I'm trying to use **twilio** taskrouter in my react app, but I keep getting this error and I don't know why.
This is the part of the code where I get the erro.

```
axios.get('url')
    .then((resp => {
        console.log("TASKROUTER", resp.data);
        var worker = new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(resp.data)
    })
```

And this is the error message:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'Worker' of undefined

Comment: what are you getting on resp.data??

Comment: Have you tried splitting up `new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(resp.data)` in multiple steps? Create the Twilio object, get the TaskRouter and then the worker? One of the first two might fail.

Comment: im getting Worker token on resp.data

Comment: @Markus Deibel i dont know how to :'(